# Add Integer Data Type in Multipart Form Content C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httprequest, multipartform-data

```
 using (var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
    
    
     HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
     multipartFormContent.Add( seq, "SequenceId"); // **

    }
```

** I want to send the "seq" as an integer in request as the HTTP Request is multipart form request it takes the strings.
Any way to pass the integer here
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any answer?

Comment: Yes, I added the solution, I found.

Answer (score 1):

**I find this solution, Hope it works for you too. Good Luck**

```
         using (var multipartFormContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
           
            var client_PostManCS = new RestClient(_URL_);
            client_PostManCS.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            request.AddParameter("UserId", _IntegerValue_); // **
            IRestResponse response = client_PostManCS.Execute(request);
         }
```